# VC2005 Debug Cannot break where breakpoint is set. Always step to wrong place

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I'm debugging my win32 solution with vc2005.
The solution contains several dlls and libs
Some problem occurs in a lib project. And I want to set some breakpoints in the source files.
However, I cannot step to correct breakpoints though I'm sure that the code around the breakpoints is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the breakpoint red or dimmed? If it is dimmed, you might need a rebuild and attach to the process again with the debugger.